# Inserted entries aren't remaining permanent in the db

Tags: java, insert, hsqldb, mybatis

Good morning,

yesterday I used for the first time MyBatis. As a starting point I used the [example](https://github.com/loiane/ibatis-helloworld) from [Loiane Groner](http://loianegroner.com/2011/02/getting-started-with-ibatis-mybatis-xml-configuration/). And I tried to replace the mysql db with an internal hsqldb (v1.8). I changed everything but I never got the insert unit test to work as expected. See below, first all necessary parts.

```xml
<insert id="insert" parameterType="Contact">
    INSERT INTO CONTACT ( CONTACT_EMAIL, CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_PHONE ) 
        VALUES ( #{email}, #{name}, #{phone} );
</insert>
```

```java
public void insert(Contact contact){

   SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();

   try {
        session.insert("Contact.insert", contact);
        session.commit();
   } finally {
        session.close();
   }
}
```

```java
@Test
public void testInsert() {

    Contact actual = new Contact();
    actual.setName("Adam");
    actual.setPhone("+001 811 23456");
    actual.setEmail("anonym@gmail.com");
    contactDAO.insert( actual );

    assertEquals(1, contactDAO.selectAll().size() );
}
```

This test will pass, because with the select method I'll retrieve the contact I inserted before. But if I open the hsqldb there is no contact ( entry ) in. 
I acutally would expect, that this test would only pass once. And if I call it a second time there should be a more than one entry. But this dosn't happen. Why, doesn't stay the contact permant? (There is no cleanup method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your settings for HSQLDB are the default settings.

With default settings, the database has a WRITE DELAY. This is normally fine for application embedded databases, but you need to turn off WRITE DELAY for testing if you expect the changes to be persisted immediately. Use `hsqldb.write_delay=false` as a connection property.

An alternative is to SHUTDOWN the database at the end of the test. You can add the connection property `shutdown=true` and explicitly close all your database connections at the end of the test.

These properties are the same in HSQLDB 1.8 and 2.x and documented here:
http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html

Comment: Yes this worked but only in combination with UNPOOLED as data source type. With pooled it didn't work. Thank you. Sincerely

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the issue has to do with the `try...finally` block in the insert method. Personally, I think that leaving out even a `catch(Exception e){log.error(e)}` is bad policy and a disservice.

I don't know about `hsqldb` specifically, but, I have seen, in certain DB's, if an error happens during the call to "commit", it will continue to show rows which shouldn't exist. I'll bet that's what's happening here.

Try adding `catch(Exception e){log.error(e)}` before the `finally` in the insert method.

Comment: There is no exception be thrown. And thanks for the tipp i didn't see the missing catch part :)